# How do I figure out a per square inch price?

Tags: calculus

How do I figure out a per square inch price? For example: If a print is 24x24 inches, and the price is $800.00, what is the price per square inch?

Thank you!

Comment: How many square inches are there in a $24\times24$ inch print?